# Cannot use Auth::routes(); outside default routes/web.php

Tags: laravel

I have a simple app with a Group in RouteServiceProvider..

```
// Web routes
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com']), function()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace);
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });


     // Match any other domains or subdomains
    Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/org.php'));
    });

}
```

In `routes/web.php` i can call `Auth::routes();` fine;

but in `routes/org.php` i get a missing required parameters from my views that need the named auth routes (made by default laravel)

> "Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login]. (View: .../resources/views/layouts/loginmenu.blade.php) (View: .."

Comment: i think  Auth::routes() need to be global not only specific to subdomain and you are getting this error because of your example.com is looking for login route and not finding it. To make it work you can include your `org.php` in web.php and should work

Comment: why do you need to use another router? - I think this is not necessary

Comment: @kamiyar Most views aside from login/register are unique.

Example: 
Diff controllers for get('/' , ) based on route group. would rather do this in an organized file vs inside a nested function.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was not the Auth::routes function but the fact that the {domain} wildcard did not set a domain in the routes (as it would without the wildcard)

To use default auth routes naming conventions you must update the views to include the domain parameter next to the name.

example:

`{{ route('login') }}`

needs to be

`{{ route('login', ['domain'=>$domain]) }}`

Of couse you must make the Domain variable available in views. The easiest way (instead of passing it around the controller like a maniac is to simply share the domain variable with the view.

In my middleware in the constructor of my Controller i call:

`view()->share('domain', $domain);`